# I need a fancy htaccess rewrite to query string

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite for htaccess that will take this sample url and rewrite it to the homepage and get rid of the query string.

Example:
Rewrite this:
http://www.domain.com/e-newsletters/forward/49.html?key=BkPOBo4l&tmpl=component

to this:
http://www.domain.com/

Here are the "variables" in the url:

49.html  there could be any number.html

?key=BkPOBo4l - the string "BkPOBo4l" will change

&tmpl=component will not change

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360885/htaccess-url-rewrite-remove-querystring-and-file-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect

`http://www.domain.com/e-newsletters/forward/49.html?key=BkPOBo4l&tmpl=component`

to `http://www.domain.com/`

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /e-newsletters/forward/[0-9]+\.html\?key=.+&tmpl=component [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks so much starkeen!